# Laravel eloquent where BadMethodCallException

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Reliese\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class B2 extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'b2';
    protected $primaryKey = 'kip_b1';
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'entried',
        'kip_b1'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\User::class, 'kip_b1', 'username');
    } 

    public function scopeEntried($query){
        return $query->where('entried',1);
    }
}
```

I tried `php artisan tinker`

```
App\Models\B2::entried()
```

the command prompt returned

> BadMethodCallException with message 'Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::entried()'

Comment: Which laravel version are you using? Also I have seen models extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` class. Why is your class extending `Reliese\Database\Eloquent\Model`?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.4, It's a external library. I used it to generate my model from existing databse (CLI)